# Sharepoint 2010: Missing Calendar View Buttons

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-online, calendar, view

I have a calendar view for a form library. When I look at it in SharePoint Designer (2010) it showed the buttons to toggle to Month, Week, and Day views, but when I publish it, those buttons are missing. Here's what I have for the webpart (I don't do code so you might have to spell it out for me):

```
<WebPartPages:ListViewWebPart runat="server" __MarkupType="xmlmarkup" WebPart="true" __WebPartId="{CF24FB93-E204-4C8D-864A-CBC7643947A9}" >
<WebPart xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2">
  <Title>Due Dates</Title>
  <FrameType>Default</FrameType>
  <Description />
  <IsIncluded>true</IsIncluded>
  <PartOrder>2</PartOrder>
  <FrameState>Normal</FrameState>
  <Height />
  <Width />
  <AllowRemove>true</AllowRemove>
  <AllowZoneChange>true</AllowZoneChange>
  <AllowMinimize>true</AllowMinimize>
  <AllowConnect>true</AllowConnect>
  <AllowEdit>true</AllowEdit>
  <AllowHide>true</AllowHide>
  <IsVisible>true</IsVisible>
  <DetailLink>/sites/VPRS/Projects/collaboration-space/workflowrssp/RSSP Workflow Library</DetailLink>
  <HelpLink />
  <HelpMode>Modeless</HelpMode>
  <Dir>Default</Dir>
  <PartImageSmall />
  <MissingAssembly>Cannot import this Web Part.</MissingAssembly>
  <PartImageLarge>/_layouts/images/itfl.png</PartImageLarge>
  <IsIncludedFilter />
  <ExportControlledProperties>false</ExportControlledProperties>
  <ConnectionID>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</ConnectionID>
  <ID>g_7a5538dc_38b3_48ba_9fbe_a2cb5c2a07c4</ID>
  <WebId xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ListView">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</WebId>
  <ListViewXml xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ListView">&lt;View Name=&quot;{CF24FB93-E204-4C8D-864A-CBC7643947A9}&quot; MobileView=&quot;TRUE&quot; Type=&quot;CALENDAR&quot; Hidden=&quot;TRUE&quot; Scope=&quot;Recursive&quot; DisplayName=&quot;&quot; Url=&quot;/sites/VPRS/Projects/collaboration-space/workflowrssp/SitePages/Home.aspx&quot; Level=&quot;1&quot; BaseViewID=&quot;1&quot; ContentTypeID=&quot;0x&quot; ImageUrl=&quot;/_layouts/images/dlicon.png&quot;&gt;&lt;ViewFields&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;Due_x0020_Date_x0020_2&quot;/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;Due_x0020_Date_x0020_2&quot;/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;FileLeafRef&quot;/&gt;&lt;/ViewFields&gt;&lt;CalendarViewStyles&gt;&amp;lt;CalendarViewStyle  Title=&amp;#39;Day&amp;#39; Type=&amp;#39;day&amp;#39; Template=&amp;#39;CalendarViewdayChrome&amp;#39; Sequence=&amp;#39;1&amp;#39; Default=&amp;#39;FALSE&amp;#39; /&amp;gt;&amp;lt;CalendarViewStyle  Title=&amp;#39;Week&amp;#39; Type=&amp;#39;week&amp;#39; Template=&amp;#39;CalendarViewweekChrome&amp;#39; Sequence=&amp;#39;2&amp;#39; Default=&amp;#39;FALSE&amp;#39; /&amp;gt;&amp;lt;CalendarViewStyle  Title=&amp;#39;Month&amp;#39; Type=&amp;#39;month&amp;#39; Template=&amp;#39;CalendarViewmonthChrome&amp;#39; Sequence=&amp;#39;3&amp;#39; Default=&amp;#39;TRUE&amp;#39; /&amp;gt;&lt;/CalendarViewStyles&gt;&lt;ViewData&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;Principle_x0020_Investigator0&quot; Type=&quot;CalendarMonthTitle&quot;/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;Principle_x0020_Investigator0&quot; Type=&quot;CalendarWeekTitle&quot;/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;Sponsor&quot; Type=&quot;CalendarWeekLocation&quot;/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;Project_x0020_ID&quot; Type=&quot;CalendarDayTitle&quot;/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;Sponsor&quot; Type=&quot;CalendarDayLocation&quot;/&gt;&lt;/ViewData&gt;&lt;Query&gt;&lt;Where&gt;&lt;And&gt;&lt;DateRangesOverlap&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;Due_x0020_Date_x0020_2&quot;/&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;Due_x0020_Date_x0020_2&quot;/&gt;&lt;Value Type=&quot;DateTime&quot;&gt;&lt;Month/&gt;&lt;/Value&gt;&lt;/DateRangesOverlap&gt;&lt;Neq&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;_Status&quot;/&gt;&lt;Value Type=&quot;Text&quot;&gt;Completed&lt;/Value&gt;&lt;/Neq&gt;&lt;/And&gt;&lt;/Where&gt;&lt;/Query&gt;&lt;Aggregations Value=&quot;Off&quot;/&gt;&lt;RowLimit&gt;0&lt;/RowLimit&gt;&lt;Mobile MobileItemLimit=&quot;3&quot;/&gt;&lt;XslLink Default=&quot;TRUE&quot;&gt;main.xsl&lt;/XslLink&gt;&lt;Toolbar Type=&quot;Standard&quot;/&gt;&lt;ParameterBindings&gt;&lt;ParameterBinding Name=&quot;NoAnnouncements&quot; Location=&quot;Resource(wss,noitemsinview_doclibrary)&quot;/&gt;&lt;ParameterBinding Name=&quot;NoAnnouncementsHowTo&quot; Location=&quot;Resource(wss,noitemsinview_doclibrary_howto2)&quot;/&gt;&lt;/ParameterBindings&gt;&lt;/View&gt;</ListViewXml>
  <ListName xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ListView">{22B1A5A0-16BF-4E89-80B9-BA68DB7D3E01}</ListName>
  <ListId xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ListView">22b1a5a0-16bf-4e89-80b9-ba68db7d3e01</ListId>
  <ViewFlag xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ListView">11014157</ViewFlag>
  <ViewFlags xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ListView">Html TabularView Hidden Recursive Calendar FilesOnly Mobile</ViewFlags>
  <ViewContentTypeId xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ListView">0x</ViewContentTypeId>
</WebPart>
</WebPartPages:ListViewWebPart>
```